# Is it possible to override DownloadFileAsync from WebClient c# for not overwriting / replace the downloaded file?

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadfileasync

My goal is to continue downloading some file after a download has been paused starting from the latest written bytes and not from 0.
I've already added **addRange headers** into my custom class (which is working as expected) but DownloadFileAsync by default overwrites my downloaded file thus creating it from scratch.

**Here's my custom class:**

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private class CookieContainer
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _cookies;

        public string this[Uri url]
        {
            get
            {
                if (_cookies.TryGetValue(url.Host, out string cookie))
                    return cookie;

                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                _cookies[url.Host] = value;
            }
        }

        public CookieContainer()
        {
            _cookies = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
    }

    private CookieContainer cookies;

    private readonly long from;
    private readonly long to;

    public CookieAwareWebClient(long from, long to) : base()
    {
        cookies = new CookieContainer();
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            string cookie = cookies[address];
            if (cookie != null)
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers.Set("cookie", cookie);

            if (from != 0 || to != 0)
            {
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).AddRange(from, to);
            }
        }

        return request;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);

        string[] cookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
        if (cookies != null && cookies.Length > 0)
        {
            string cookie = "";
            foreach (string c in cookies)
                cookie += c;

            this.cookies[response.ResponseUri] = cookie;
        }

        return response;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);

        string[] cookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
        if (cookies != null && cookies.Length > 0)
        {
            string cookie = "";
            foreach (string c in cookies)
                cookie += c;

            this.cookies[response.ResponseUri] = cookie;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DownloadFileAsync` is not virtual so you cannot override it.

`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` method is a convenient way to download a file from network location, it simply accepts a URL and a local path and does the job. The requirement of pause-and-resume is not in the scope of this API, you must write some code to read from the response stream, and write to the file stream (which you open from the existing file in Append mode).

Comment: Is it possible to provide one example with such method for webclient.DownloadFileAsync? (I want to avoid changing all code to httpwebrequest)

Comment: You can add a new method like `DownloadFileWithRange` to your custom class, I find an example [from here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/307548/Resume-Suppoert-Downloading). You don't need to set the range (from, to) explicitly as you do, the code can detect the content-length of the network resource, and the file-length of the local file, and calculate the range for you.